# Like std::function but with more varied argument and return types

Tags: c++, c++20, std-function, stdany

I'm in search of a way to set up and call functions with arbitrary arguments and return types. One use case would be high level scripting. Something like this:

```
// universal function
using dynfunction = std::any (*)(std::vector<std::any> args);
```

I made a simplified example:

```
#include <any>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::string_literals;
using namespace std::string_view_literals;

class MyClass {
public:
    int foo(double d, std::string m) {
        std::cout << "foo " << d << ", " << m << std::endl;
        return 42;
    }

    virtual double bar(int i) {
        return -i;
    }
};

class MyDerivedClass : public MyClass {
    virtual double bar(int i) override {
        return -i*3.1412;
    }
};

void foobar(char c) {
    std::cout << "foobar " << c << std::endl;
}

// universal function
using dynfunction = std::any (*)(std::vector<std::any> args);

// caller wrappers
std::any call_foo(std::vector<std::any> args) {
    return std::any_cast<MyClass*>(args[0])->foo(std::any_cast<double>(args[1]), std::any_cast<std::string>(args[2]));
}

std::any call_bar(std::vector<std::any> args) {
    return std::any_cast<MyClass*>(args[0])->bar(std::any_cast<int>(args[1]));
}

std::any call_foobar(std::vector<std::any> args) {
    foobar(std::any_cast<char>(args[0]));
    return {}; // void
}

// demonstrate dynamic resolution
std::map<const std::string_view, const dynfunction> functions = {
        { "foo"sv, call_foo },
        { "bar"sv, call_bar },
        { "foobar"sv, call_foobar }
};

int main() {
    MyClass obj;
    std::any ret = functions["foo"sv](std::vector<std::any>{&obj, 7.0, "Hello World!"s});
    ret = functions["bar"sv](std::vector<std::any>{&obj, ret});
    std::cout << "obj.bar returned " << std::any_cast<double>(ret) << std::endl;
    MyDerivedClass obj2;
    ret = functions["bar"sv](std::vector<std::any>{dynamic_cast<MyClass*>(&obj2), 11}); // derived class must be cast to base
    std::cout << "obj2.bar returned " << std::any_cast<double>(ret) << std::endl;
    functions["foobar"sv](std::vector<std::any>{'x'});
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rMcTo9

This works, but I wonder if there are simpler or more direct ways.

Also, one thing that bothers me is the need to cast polymorphic types i.e. objects of derived classes to the right base class for this to work (see `obj2` in the example). Is there a way around this?

Note: the example is deliberately simplified (use of `std::vector` for arguments, `std::map` for lookup, these are just conceptual stand-ins).

**Edit**: It seems more information is needed.

This is part of a "Model-driven architecture" (MDA) (not the OMG variant - our solution predates that by ~6 years). We have our own OOP/4GL language "V" we created in 1995. It retains all meta information at runtime. This allows us to generate all GUI, database design, data binding, Scripting interface you-name-it dynamically. In other languages this is nowadays called "Reflection", but what is available in Java&Co is quite limited in comparison to what we can do.

The MDA means (among many other things) that we need a way to transfer control from the dynamic "model driven" part of the solution to the actual application logic i.e. the functions. The built-in scripting language we have is just one of many use cases, and I thought it is the easiest to understand for a general audience.

The amount of primitive data types is limited, while there are thousands of polymorphic data types. `std::any` seemed more elegant than `std::variant` because a) it has this cool but completely transparent heap optimization, (i.e. small data types need no dynamic allocation) and b) we can keep separation of concerns intact between the data types i.e. all the `std::any` handling code can remain unchanged if we add a new data type. But if there are important advantages for `std::variant`, I'm open to consider it.

Comment: If you try to use this approach in an actual practical use case, you will probably find that it is not useful. You need to already know the correct argument type before you call the function or the `any_cast` fail. There is a similar problem with the return type, you need to know what type the `std::any` will hold. So there isn't really any benefit to hiding that information.

Comment: There are very practical use cases. We have a system like that implemented in C/macros and in extensive use for 25 years. Now we would like to modernize it using C++.

Comment: If you are trying to convert a macro-based system to C++, there will be a non-`std::any` solution using templates which will be much better. Edit : The benefit of type punning is to allow various types to be treated uniformly, but you can't do that with `std::any` as you need outside information on the actual type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: That kind of depends on what the macros under discussion are doing. If they're used to unpack the parameters to this "dynamic functions", then templates wouldn't really help.

Comment: @markus you provided clarity with your comment -- you are trying to modernize an existing macro-based solution.  We can not see what this macro solution does, but it is **very unlikely** that `std::any` is a modern equivalent of what your macros are doing.

Comment: If you want to do high-level scripting, you should, perhaps, use something like python, which supports what you want natively.

Comment: @DrewDormann: This seems like the standard use case for `any`: there's a source and destination that both know what types are involved, but the passage happens through an intermediary that *doesn't* need to know the types. An intermediary that is used for multiple such calls involving different types.

Comment: Please show us a use case, so we can all be on the same page. I can't think of one right now.

Comment: @NicolBolas I agree with all that you say here.  I am speaking to the unseen macro system, and _guessing_ that these macros are not doing what `std::any` does.  That might mean that `std::any` is measurably an improvement, but that is a lot of guessing about unseen code.

Comment: @DrewDormann: The "unseen macro system" is an irrelevant background detail. The OP has asked a question about making these "dynamic functions" work better.

Comment: There will only be a limited set off possible primitive data types plus a huge class hierarchy. The data comes from a dynamic/untyped source such as the text of a script. Simplified example: if it sees `1` it will add an `int` to the arguments, if it sees `1.0` it will add a `double` etc. (in reality there is runtime meta information available about the signatures, so parameter validation and conversion is possible, but I wanted to keep it simple here).

Comment: @markus it may help to [edit] your question to include all relevant details.  It seems to be unclear whether your comments are part of the question.

Comment: @markus: "*There will only be a limited set off possible primitive data types plus a huge class hierarchy.*" Well now you've changed the nature of the question. Now you're looking at a circumstance where `any` makes no sense, because the list of types is very *finite* and very well defined. So you should be using `variant`.

Comment: @markus: Show us the macros and we'll show you haw to translate it.  `std::any` is almost certainly not the best translation, unless your legacy C code also had insane pointer casts.  I can't think of any useful purpose for your dynamic map of functions with different signatures.

Comment: [Here is one way of transcribing that is faster and type safe](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5256bbb1738e0832) but probably loses key use cases you didn't describe. Without knowing why you want the dynamics, it's not possible to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @MooingDuck, argument vector composition is not dynamic at runtime, right? See Ayxan Haqverdili's `main()` to see what I mean.

Comment: @markus: What we're trying to explain is that there's no good reason to need dynamic dispatch to functions with different signatures.  That's just buggy code.

Comment: @markus: "*there are thousands of polymorphic data types*" If they all derive from the same base class, then there is only one "polymorphic data type".

Comment: @NicolBolas, true. And the `std::variant` you suggested, would allow specifying it, i.e. no cast needed in the dynamic call. But the wrapper/binding code would still need to check the derived type with the function signature. Which could probably be done using `dynamic_cast<>`, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my design:

```
#include <any>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class Dyn_fun final {
 public:
  using arg_type = std::vector<std::any>;
  using return_type = std::any;

  Dyn_fun() = default;

  template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
  explicit Dyn_fun(Ret (*fp)(Args...)) : m_dispatcher{make_dispatcher(fp)} {}

  template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
  Dyn_fun& operator=(Ret (*fp)(Args...)) {
    set_function(fp);
    return *this;
  }

  template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
  void set_function(Ret (*fp)(Args...)) {
    m_dispatcher = make_dispatcher(fp);
  }

  explicit operator bool() const noexcept {
    return static_cast<bool>(m_dispatcher);
  }
  bool operator==(std::nullptr_t) const noexcept {
    return m_dispatcher == nullptr;
  }
  bool operator!=(std::nullptr_t) const noexcept { return !(*this == nullptr); }

  return_type operator()(arg_type const& args) { return m_dispatcher(args); }

 private:
  using dispatcher_type = std::function<return_type(arg_type const&)>;

  template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
  static auto make_dispatcher(Ret (*fp)(Args...)) {
    return make_dispatcher(fp, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
  }

  // Extracts type at a specific index of argument pack
  template <size_t index, typename... Args>
  using type_at = std::decay_t<decltype(std::get<index>(
      std::declval<std::tuple<Args...>>()))>;

  template <typename Ret, typename... Args, size_t... Indices>
  static auto make_dispatcher(Ret (*fun)(Args...),
                              std::index_sequence<Indices...>) {
    return [fun](arg_type const& args) {
      if (args.size() != sizeof...(Args))
        throw std::runtime_error{"Argument count does not match"};

      // this avoids std::any{ void }
      if constexpr (!std::is_void_v<Ret>) {
        return std::any(
            fun(std::any_cast<type_at<Indices, Args...>>(args[Indices])...));
      } else {
        fun(std::any_cast<type_at<Indices, Args...>>(args[Indices])...);
        return std::any{};
      }
    };
  }

  dispatcher_type m_dispatcher;
};

int foo(int i, char const* s, double d) {
  return std::printf("foo: %d, %s, %.2f\n", i, s, d);
}

void print_sum(int a, int b) {
  std::printf("print_sum: %d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a + b);
}

int main() {
  // Construct with foo
  Dyn_fun dyn_fun(foo);

  Dyn_fun::arg_type args{10, "Hello", 4.2};

  // Call with arguments
  dyn_fun(args);

  // Change the wrapped function
  dyn_fun = print_sum;

  // with different arguments
  args.assign({10, 20});

  // Call the new function
  dyn_fun(args);
}
```

Highlights:

- The class does all the boilerplate casting and calling the wrapped function.
- Can be assigned any function dynamically.

Comment: The automatic generation is great! But the template `operator()` does not work because argument composition is dynamic at runtime (that's the whole point). However, if you add 
    return_type operator()(arg_type args) {
        return m_dispatcher(args);
    } 
it works

Comment: Test code:
```
   Dyn_fun::arg_type args;
    args.push_back(10);
    args.push_back("Hello");
    args.push_back(42.0);
    
    dyn_foo(args);
```

Comment: @markus that does make sense. I've changed the call operator accordingly.

Comment: This would also work in a similar way with a `std::variant` argument type, right? I guess I could solve the `obj2` problem (see question) that way.

Comment: @markus yes, this should works similarly if you switch `std::any`-related stuff with `std::variant`