# How to design a container that can hold any type functions in c++?

Tags: c++

I want the server to support registering any functions.
may something like these:

```cpp
server.register("Add", [](int a, int b){cout << a+b << endl;});
server.register("Echo", [](string str){ cout << str << endl; });
...
server.Call("Add", 12, 13);
```

However, how can I hold all these functions? They have different arguments.
Is there any method like this: `unordered_map<string, ?> functions_`

Comment: `std::any` type?

Comment: I tried it. std::any can refer to different type values, int, 'double', ... . But it seems unable to refer different functions

Comment: How would the code know how to call a function with unknown parameter types and number?  This feels like an XY-Problem.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624017/c0x-storing-any-type-of-stdfunction-in-a-stdmap) might help.

Comment: You can't hold a "function" in c++.

Comment: would you be ok with `server.Call("Add", make_tuple(12, 13));` ?

Comment: @RicharCritten the number of parameters is not unknown. In the example the "Add"s lambdas `operator()` has two. `Call("Add", 12, 13)` takes `2` too. Not saying it would be simple, but its not impossible

Comment: This can be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66264598

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45718187/2610810

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an implementation that uses `any` ([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MEnx54dn8)):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <any>

using namespace std;

class server_t
{
public:

  template <typename F>
  void register_function(const string& name, F&& fun)
  {
    m[name] = function(forward<F>(fun));
  }

  template <typename... A>
  void call(const string& name, A&&... args)
  {
    auto it = m.find(name);
    if (it == m.end())
      throw logic_error(name + " not found");
    else
      any_cast<function<void(A...)>>(it->second)(forward<A>(args)...);
  }

private:
  map<string, any> m;
};

int main()
{
  server_t server;

  server.register_function("Add", [](int a, int b) { cout << a + b << endl; });
  server.register_function("Echo", [](string s) { cout << s << endl; });

  try
  {
    server.call("Add", 1, 2);
    server.call("Echo", string("Howdy!"));
    server.call("Subtract", 2, 1); // will throw: wrong name
    server.call("Add", 1, 2, 3); // will throw: wrong number of arguments
    server.call("Add", 1, 2.3); // will throw: wrong argument type (double instead of int)
  }
  catch (const exception& e)
  {
    cout << e.what();
  }
}
```

**[EDIT]**

*"...if i want to register like this : server. Register(..., [](string s, string& t){ t=s; }). Then, a failure will occur."*

`call` is not able to infer the types of arguments that the stored function expects. If you don't pass the exact types it expects, `any_cast` will fail - which is better than crashing the application. The following should work:

```
//...
server.register_function("Put", [](const string& s, string& d) { d = s; });

try
{
  const string s = "abc";
  string d;
  server.call("Put", s, d);
  server.call<const string&, string&>("Put", "xyz", d);
  //...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried it, and it can work well. However, if i want to register like this : server.register(..., [](string s, string& t){ t=s; }). Then, a failure will occur. the reason is that `it=m.find(name)` will be nullptr.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best solution, but something like the following works for your example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
 
class Server {
private:
    using erasedType = void (*)();
    unordered_map<string, erasedType> funcs;
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    void Register(const string& name, void (*func)(Args...)) {
        funcs[name] = reinterpret_cast<erasedType>(func);
    }
 
    template<typename... Args>
    void Call(const string& name, Args... args) {
        using funcType = void (*)(Args...);
        auto func = reinterpret_cast<funcType>(funcs.at(name));
        return func(args...);
    }
};
 
int main() {
    Server server;
    server.Register("Add", +[](int a, int b){ cout << a+b << endl; });
    server.Register("Echo", +[](string str){ cout << str << endl; });
 
    server.Call("Add", 12, 13);
    server.Call("Echo", string("hello"));
 
    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/vfaJfH)

Note, this approach works only for C-style function pointers, as a function pointer of one type is allowed to be casted to a function pointer of another type. This includes **non-capturing** lambdas, which are convertible to function pointers.

This approach will not work for other types of callables, including **capturing** lambdas, functors, etc.

However, be *very* careful with the parameters you pass to `Call()`. If you don't match the parameter types correctly, *undefined behavior* occurs. For instance, the need to pass `"hello“` as `std::string("Hello")`, otherwise the `Echo()` lambda gets invoked as `void(*)(const char*)` instead of as `void(*)(std::string)`, so its `std::string` parameter won't get constructed properly.

Comment: very easy to use wrong. Not sure if this is UB already https://godbolt.org/z/hY3Ysq8j4